# Senti_classifier not showing any polarity

Tags: python, classification, nltk, data-mining, sentiment-analysis

My sentiment analysis code is not giving any polarity.
This is the code.

```
from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
sentences = ['The movie was the worst movie', 'It was the worst acting by the actors']
pos_score, neg_score = senti_classifier.polarity_scores(sentences)
print pos_score, neg_score
```

I am getting a polarity of 0,0.
I do not understand why. Do I have to train data?
I thought it was included in the nltk library.
Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: It doesn't seem a NLTK problem but related to the library "sentiment_classifier": did you install all the dependencies?

Comment: Did you *train* the classifier?

Comment: I did not train the classifier because the source from where i got it said i dont need any extra training,

Comment: yes,i did install all the dependencies.

Comment: Never mind,i did some editing in the .py file and got the required result.